# UICollectionView working on iOS7 but not on iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My `UICollectionView` cells don't get displayed on iOS6, because my delegate method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` doesn't get called. I suspect because of this warning:

```
 the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
 the item height must be less that the height of the `UICollectionView`
 minus the section inset's top and bottom values.
```

I don't get the warning on iOS7, and all the cells display correctly there too.

I've set my `collectionView` frame to height 270 in the `.xib` and there are no insets defined.
I've set my cell height to 270 in the `.xib`.
I can print out my `collectionView` frame at runtime and it's 271.

Also, my `collectionview` is actually inside a custom `tableview` cell.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed my problem! In my `.xib`, setting my **Collection View Size** Cell Size to a smaller value.

My setup is that I have this `collectionview` inside a custom `tableview` cell and 
I do return the height of my `tableview` cell programatically (depending on the content). So it could be that my warnings had to do with my `collectionview` not fitting inside the `tableview` cell. So setting the initial `collectionview` to a smaller value fixed it.

I was on the wrong path thinking that the problem was with my `collectionview` and its `colletionview` cell.

Maybe?

Answer (score 8):

Try to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO`

This was introduced in [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7) so you might want to wrap that with an [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) version check, if you are supporting [ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6) and below.

Comment: not really clear why this works but it just cleared a UICollectionViewFlowLayout warning I've been debugging for the past two hours. Thanks!

Comment: it's actually working fine on ios7 so unfortunately this property won't help me in this case as i'm seeing the issue on ios6.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

actually did the trick. it also resolved my issue in swift, where the cells of a horizontal flow layout had a frame top of -32 (???) and did not fit into the collection view properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to manually set `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.itemSize` in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
   self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.itemSize = CGRectMake(...);
}
```

Another possibility to generate the same trick would be to implement the method
`collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: thx for the question edit. My collectionview is actually a component in a custom tableview cell. bit confused where to place this line of code?

Comment: a VC's viewWillLayoutSubviews is called whenever the main frame changes (during initial layout, rotation, etc). It's just a method you override (default does nothing).  I'm guessing that doesn't do you much good in your case.    On the question edit, I fixed the "that" v "than" typo, then I noticed in another question that it's actually Apple's typo!

Comment: haha yes it always bugs me to see this typo! See my answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, in my case the size of collectionCell in storyboard is 96x96 and also under `-(CGSize)collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`

the solution was **removing** this delegate:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {.left = 10, .right = 10, .top = 5, .bottom = 5};

    return insets;
}
```

And by the way this is under ios7, it's late but hope this will help some.. Cheers..

Answer (score -1):

Set:

```
self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
```